# Is it safe to force unwrap an optional after checking it is not nil

Tags: swift

I have a network method that return me a completion closure with an `Error` as the parameter.

I usually avoid force unwrapping, but in that case, I use a `guard` statement to check if `error` is not `nil`:

```
guard error == nil else {
    print(error!)
    return
}

...
```

The method I'm calling is from an SDK so I don't really know what happens in there.

In general, is this force unwrapping thread safe or not?

Comment: Do you mean "safe" or "thread safe"? They are different.

Comment: In your case it is safe, but I would consider it bad practice. You should avoid force-unwrapping optionals, even when you've verified it's safe, unless there isn't another reasonable way to do it. In this case, `if let error = error` is how optionals are meant to be unwrapped.

Comment: @paper1111 I meant thread safe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference between `if` and `guard` is just simple, but in your case, you should use `if`, not `guard`. `guard` should be used when some values are expected to be present for the function to execute as intended. You *don't* want `error` to be present, but if it is not `nil`, you have to `return`. So you should use `if let`:

```
if let error = error {
    print(error)
    return
}
```

This way, you don't need to use force unwrapping and it improves how your code is represented.

Back to your question "In general, is this force unwrapping thread safe or not?", assuming that you are really talking about thread safety, it is certainly thread safe. Closure variables are immutable.

If you are talking about safety (ie will "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" occur), it is also certainly safe. `error` must not be `nil` before you can unwrap it (because of `guard`), so the force unwrapping is safe.

In conclusion, your current code is bulletproof, but using `if let` might be better.

Comment: I used `guard` to deal with the error at first. Quick question, what if it wasn't in a closure?

Comment: Yes it would still be thread safe. Unwrapping doesn't modify a variable.

Comment: No indeed but what if this variable (being a reference to an object) was modified by another thread after it was safely unwrapped but before any call on this variable was done?

Comment: So unless we are safe-unwrapping, the guard statement doesn't guarantee thread safety or nil safety?

Comment: @urgentx assume `foo` is an optional, using `guard let foo = foo else { return }` will allow you to use `foo` in your later code without unwrapping (`nil` safety), which prevents you from having pyramids of `if let`.

Comment: Yep, I'm just wondering about the guarantees of nil and thread safety if we just use `guard foo != nil else { return } //Can we safely assume foo is not nil here?` Couldn't foo be modified by another thread after the guard statement, if it's a field for example?

Comment: @urgentx If it is immutable (`let`), it will be safe. If it is mutable (`var`), it is not safe.