# force unwrapping after checking if nil?

Tags: swift

Is it considered bad practice to do this

I am checking if the array is nil, then force unwrapping to retrieve an element from the array.  I am doing this to avoid creating an unnecessary if let variable.

```
if self.arrayOfStrings != nil{
    textLabel.text = self.arrayOfStrings![0]
}
```

Comment: Other than it not being as readable, it should be fine.

Comment: The `if let` variable is not unnecessary. You will use it inside the `if`. That's the whole point.

Comment: He is saying that creating that variable is costing him memory. So by force unwrapping, he is saving that much memory.

Comment: I think, by *unnecessary*, OP means extra memory allocation that can be avoided in this case @rmaddy.

Comment: `textLabel.text = arrayOfStrings?.first`

Comment: @LeoDabus even though this is not an answer to the question, it's the best solution in this case.

Comment: How about declaring the array as non-optional? in most cases an empty array for *no data* is sufficient

Comment: @RakeshaShastri The OP does not say that (at least explicitly) and there wouldn't be any extra memory use anyway.

Comment: And don't forget to check if the array indices contains the index before trying to subscript your array

Comment: Also why is the editor unable to detect i am checking if self.arrayOfStrings is nil or not, but knows that an if let variable has been checked already.  In other words, why is it forcing me to use '!' .

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29717210/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48858725/1187415

Comment: @BrainGreen What makes you think that optional binding takes more memory?

Comment: @Alexander I guess my question is twofold, i wanted to avoid creating a new variable for readability, and i did assume a new variable would require the allocation of more memory.

Comment: @BrianGreen The fact that you checked for `!= nil` on one line does not in any way change the fact that on the next line it is still optional and could still be `nil`.

Comment: @BrianGreen And please [edit] your question with any clarifications. Posting comments is not a good way to post clarifications.

Comment: @rmaddy I see, the if let variable would not be an optional, but the arrayOfStrings is still a declared optional type.

Comment: @BrianGreen You can conditionally bind an optional to a non-optional local variable with the same name, that shadows the optional. `if let arrayOfStrings = self.arrayOfStrings { ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is bad practice. Perhaps not in this case specifically but it is possible that some other thread could update the property and make it nil between this thread checking for `nil` and then force-unwrapping.

Just do:

```
if let arrayOfStrings = self.arrayOfStrings {
    textLabel.text = arrayOfStrings[0]
}
```

There is no unnecessary variable here since you actually use the variable inside the `if let`.

Of course in this very specific case of trying to get the first value of an optional array, you can simply do:

```
textLabel.text = self.arrayOfStrings?.first
```

If you actually wanted something other than index 0, you should check the index:

```
if let arrayOfStrings = self.arrayOfStrings, someIndex < arrayOfStrings.count {
    textLabel.text = arrayOfStrings[someIndex]
}
```

In none of these cases is the "extra" variable a waste of effort or memory. It is being used in a read-only capacity as a constant and Swift is smart enough not to create a complete copy of the array in the process.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it considered bad practice to do this
>
> ```
> if self.arrayOfStrings != nil{
>     textLabel.text = self.arrayOfStrings![0]
> }
> ```

Not bad practice, and I do sometimes do it; but it is unnecessary and a bit unusual, because this is the situation that conditional bindings are intended to resolve.

> I am checking if the array is nil, then force unwrapping to retrieve an element from the array. I am doing this to avoid creating an unnecessary if let variable.

"Creating an `if let` variable" is not "unnecessary". It is the elegant way to handle this. What *you* are proposing to do is what is "unnecessary" (and it is wasteful because you are compelling the runtime to access `self.arrayOfStrings` twice).

You have two choices, depending on whether everything needs to come to a halt if `arrayOfStrings` is `nil`.

You can put a guard:

```
guard let arr = self.arrayOfStrings else {return}
textLabel.text = arr[0]
```

Or you can use a conditional binding:

```
if let arr = self.arrayOfStrings {
    textLabel.text = arr[0]
}
```

The difference (aside from the early exit) is the scope of `arr`.

So, although to some extent this is a matter of opinion, I would say that the problem here lies in your sense of what is elegant.